# Chart.js canvas doesn't render but renders after zooming out or zooming in

Tags: chart.js

I am using Chart.js and since I upgraded Chrome to Version 60.0.3112.90, the Charts (donuts, bar charts) do not render, but they do when I zoom in or zoom out or even if I get back to original zoom (anything which forces canvas re-render). But it doesn't show up on the first load. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: can you produce a fiddle which shows this?